# Eclipse P2 - touchpoint for the collect action is not included

Tags: eclipse, equinox, p2

I keep getting this error in my RCP application any time I try to install the Eclipse Platform Launchers feature in my rcp app.

Feature id I'm installing: org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature.group 3.5.1.v20111216-1653-7P7NFUIFIbaUcU77s0KQWHw5HZTZ

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 4 2012-07-31 14:59:58.501
!MESSAGE An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2012-07-31 14:59:58.501
!MESSAGE session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=null --> [R]org.eclipse.equinox.executable_root.gtk.linux.x86_64 3.5.1.v20111216-1653-7P7NFUIFIbaUcU77s0KQWHw5HZTZ, action=).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2012-07-31 14:59:58.501
!MESSAGE The required Touchpoint: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.native 1.0.0 touchpoint for the collect action is not included in the installation manager configuration.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The required Touchpoint: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.native 1.0.0 touchpoint for the collect action is not included in the installation manager configuration.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ActionManager.getTouchpointQualifiedActionId(ActionManager.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect.getActions(Collect.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.InstallableUnitPhase.getActions(InstallableUnitPhase.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.mainPerform(Phase.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningSession.performProvisioningPlan(ProvisioningSession.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProfileModificationJob.runModal(ProfileModificationJob.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make sure bundle '**org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives**' and its dependencies packaged in your application.

Comment: If anyone is following the RCP p2 tutorial on Lars Vogel's website, this is something he missed and needs to be included for the tutorial to work, at least with Eclipse 4.3.1 (Kepler).